# Area of Parallelogram in an Ellipse

Tags: optimization, conic-sections, area

> A parallelogram is inscribed in the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ with the fixed line $y=mx$ as one of its diagonals. Prove that the maximum area of the parallelogram is $2ab$.

First I found out the the points of intersection of the line with the ellipse by putting $y=mx$ in the ellipse equation. This is what I got,
 $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{m^2x^2}{b^2}=1$$
 $$\implies x^2(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{m^2}{b^2})=1$$ 
 $$\implies x=\pm\frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2m^2+b^2}}$$

This gives me,
 $$ y=\pm\frac{mab}{\sqrt{a^2m^2+b^2}}$$

So, I got the two points where the line intersects the ellipse. I don't know hoew to proceed from here. Do I have to find the point on the ellipse which is at a maximum distance from the line? If yes, how? If no, then how do I solve it?

Comment: You should be able to find the distance $D(x,y)$ from a point $(x,y)$ to the line $y=mx$. Then you should be able to maximize $D$, subject to $(x,y)$ being on the ellipse.

Comment: Will you please explain how to do that?

Comment: Can you not find the distance from a point to a line? You may be biting off more than you can chew, if that's the case.

Comment: No, I can find the distance of a point from a line but you were talking about maximizing it. How do I maximize the distance? What do you mean by that ?

Comment: So, what formula did you get for the distance $D(x,y)$?

Comment: By the way, you do realize that you have accepted an answer that has been acknowledged as incorrect by the person who posted it, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a little diagram of a canonical ellipse, and get convinced that, if the intersection points you found are $\;(\pm x_0,\pm y_0)\;,\;\;x_0,y_0>0$ , then the parallelogram's area is just

$$S(m)=(2x_0)(2y_0)=\frac{4a^2b^2m}{a^2m^2+b^2}$$

Differentiate wrt $\;m\;$ :

$$S'(m)=\frac{4a^2b^2(b^2-a^2m^2)}{(a^2m^2+b^2)^2}=0\iff m=\pm\frac ba$$

It's not hard to see we get a maximum point at $\;m=\frac ba\;$, and thus the area is

$$S\left(\frac ba\right)=\frac{4a^2b^2\frac ba}{a^2\frac{b^2}{a^2}+b^2}=\frac{4ab^3}{2b^2}=2ab$$

**Added:** The above assumes the parallelogram is a rectangle with sides parallel to the axis. Read the comments below this answer.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the parallelogram is a rectangle, and one aligned with the axes, at that.

Comment: Yes @GerryMyerson, I was although it is not given so, yet it doesn't seem to be far from this, since the origin is clearly the midpoint of the diagonal given (which, btw, intersects the ellipse at antipodal points), and thus the other diagonal must also pass through the origin...well, a little more seems to be required here, and perhaps more geometric than algebraic, but anyway I'll add an edit to my answer.

Comment: @DonAntonio (guess your comment above came in while I was typing mine above.. I'll remove that comment.

Comment: Just clarify one thing. Why am I differentiating wrt $m$. Is it because it is the only variable in the expression?

Comment: Indeed so, @Ris97 : things were done so as to express the wanted area as a function of $\;m\;$ , **yet** ... as commented by Gerry, one still has to show *first* that the maximal area is obtained when the parallelogram is in fact a rectangle. This seems to be pretty "clear" geometrically, yet it still requires some proof.

Answer (score 2):

Draw the diagonal in the ellipse, and apply an afine transformation changing the ellipse to a circle. Of all the rectangles in this circle sharing the transformed diagonal, that with the largest area will be a square, with area $2r^2$, where $r$ is the radius of the transformed original ellipse. Now afine transform back, and you have a parallelogram with the specified diagonal, and area $2ab$. Note that afine transformations preserve relative areas.
Edit: since the area of an inscribed square is larger than any non square quadrilateral inscribed in the circle, the original problem can consider all inscribed quadrilaterals sharing the given diagonal, not jut parallelograms. Further, the two diagonals of the optimum parallelogram are conjugate diameters.